# How do I use a Tokio oneshot sender and receiver on different tasks with inner loops?

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

Not sure how to handler the borrow checker here.

```rust
use tokio::sync::oneshot; // 1.0.2

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = oneshot::channel::<u8>();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            sender.send(3).unwrap();
        }
    });
}
```

Creates this error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `sender`
 --> src/main.rs:7:13
  |
7 |             sender.send(3).unwrap();
  |             ^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
  |
  = note: move occurs because `sender` has type `tokio::sync::oneshot::Sender<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. That's the entire point of a **one**shot channel: it can only be used a maximum of one time:

> A channel for sending **a single message** between asynchronous tasks.
>
> — [`tokio::sync::oneshot`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.2.0/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html)

It sounds like you want a different kind of channel, such as [`tokio::sync::mpsc`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.2.0/tokio/sync/mpsc/index.html).

---

> what if I only want to send one message at the start of the loop?

Then perform the code before the loop starts:

```rust
use tokio::sync::oneshot; // 1.0.2

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = oneshot::channel::<u8>();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        sender.send(3).unwrap();
        
        loop {
            // Do things
        }
    });
}
```

If you *had* to have it inside the loop, you need to dynamically mark the value as no longer there and handle that case. Here, I use an `Option` and `if let`:

```rust
use tokio::sync::oneshot; // 1.0.2

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = oneshot::channel::<u8>();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut sender = Some(sender);
        
        loop {
            if let Some(sender) = sender.take() {
                sender.send(3).unwrap();
            }
            // Do things
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I understand, but what if I only want to send one message at the start of the loop, is it suggested to use a `mpsc`? As I only want to send one message, is there a way to use it and throw it away?

Comment: Actually, you can if you loop over `tokio::select!`. I wanted to use canceller as a means to cancel this select-loop and tokio provides an example for this exact usecase: https://doc.servo.org/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html#examples. In short: You can select on `&mut canceller`.